# Leaflet search options for multiple markers

Tags: java, leaflet, gis

I have a leaflet project with around 150 points that should be displayed. The idea is to show the progress of a project, therefore there are 257 symbols which could be assigned to a point. And there is also a pop up which display additional infos.
The "database" is an excel sheet which gets updated regularly. So I have a python script which updates my leaflet script. This part is running fine and does what it should.

Current code

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([47.0, 9.0], 13);
 L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
  }).addTo(map);

    // show the scale bar on the lower left corner
    L.control.scale({imperial: false, metric: true}).addTo(map);

    var symb_A2_22_1 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'folder/KB-11.png',
    iconSize:     [42, 20]
    });
    
    var A2_22_1 = L.marker([47.4678,8.7049],{icon: symb_A2_22_1}).addTo(map)
                              
    A2_22_1.bindPopup("<b>A2-22-1</b><br>x<br>PWD<br>x<br>x")
    

    var symb_A2_22_100 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'folder/RS-11.png',
    iconSize:     [42, 20]
    });
    
    var A2_22_100 = L.marker([47.4708,8.7059],{icon: symb_A2_22_100}).addTo(map)
                              
    A2_22_100.bindPopup("<b>A2-22-100</b><br>x<br>PWD<br>x<br>x)
```

Now I want to add a search option to search by the name of the point. I already searched for solutions. I think I have to bring all my points into one layer. So the here ([Putting multiple markers in Layer Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756050/putting-multiple-markers-in-layer-group) )presented solution seems to be a good idea (create markers, add to layer, and then add the layer to the map and not the single markers).

However how I get the popup content and my custom symbol into the list?

Or do you have another solution to make my markers searchable?

Comment: Do you mean you not only want a search by point name, but also by popup content and progress/symbol status?

Comment: Search by name is enough